# "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet" when trying to load data into my model

Tags: python, django, model, django-settings

I am developing an app in Django.

I want to load data inside my model, that is `glossary_entry`, but the data is stored inside an xlsx file, that is `dati_prova.xlsx`.

In order to achieve this, I have developed the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

from myapp.models import glossary_entry #this is line 7
 
path=r"mypath\dati_prova.xlsx"
 
with open(path) as f:
        reader = pd.read_excel(f)
        next(reader, None)  # skip the headers

        for row in reader:
                _, created = glossary_entry.objects.get_or_create(
                Lemma = row[0],
                Acronym = row[1],
                Definizione = row[2],
                )
            # creates a tuple of the new object or
            # current object and a boolean of if it was created
```

But when I run it from Anaconda prompt, I get

> File "load_glossary.py", line 7, in module
> ...
>
> raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

What's the problem?

**Please note:**

My app runs fine, just the uploading-data script fails.

**Please note:**

I copy pasted

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()
```

from stack overflow answers because I was getting the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_TZ,
> but settings are not configured. You must either define the
> environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure() before accessing settings.

but I don't have experience and I don't understand what was the error.

### Update

I have read on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/bF_lRbzzguA that it could be that

> The problem is that one of your applications imports
> models in its top-level **init**.py. This is not supported; for an
> explanation, you can read
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded

### Update

I changed the file as following:

```
import pandas as pd

from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()

import django
django.setup() 


from myapp.models import mymodel
 
path=r"mypath\dati_prova.xlsx"
 
with open(path) as f:
        reader = pd.read_excel(f)
        next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
```

And now I get:

> RuntimeError: Model class myapp.models.mymodel doesn't declare an
> explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

But it is not true, since in settings.py I wrote my app name, and the project runs fine. Just the script does not work...
It is like python cannot read my settings.py .
What's the problem?
Maybe is it reading another set

### Update

As suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38821174/7658051 
I have moved my script `load_glossary.py` into

> myapp>management>commands

made a copy of my xlsx file into a csv one 
and updated the code as follows:

```
# myapp/management/commands/load_glossary.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import csv

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('csv_file', nargs='+', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for csv_file in options['csv_file']:
            dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_file), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            for row in dataReader:
                
                Lemma=row[0],
                Acronym=row[1],
                Definition=row[2],
                
                
                # etc...
                self.stdout.write(
                    'Created glossary entry'
                
                )
```

And I am lunching it by typing into anaconda prompt

```
python ./manage.py load_glossary csv_file "mypath\dati_prova.csv"
```

But then I get

> line 20, in handle
> dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_file), delimiter=',', quotechar='"') FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'csv_file'

What's wrong this time?

Comment: I hope it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28297987/1734707

Comment: thanks, it brought me to update the code as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58322333/7658051 but still it's like python it's not reading my settings

Comment: what you show as the latest version of your code no longer has the `from django.conf import settings` -- that would indeed prevent it from reading the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by substituting this:

```
import pandas as pd
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

from myapp.models import glossary_entry #this is line 7

path=r"mypath\dati_prova.xlsx"

with open(path) as f:
        reader = pd.read_excel(f)
        next(reader, None)  # skip the headers

        for row in reader:
                _, created = glossary_entry.objects.get_or_create(
                Lemma = row[0],
                Acronym = row[1],
                Definizione = row[2],
                )
            # creates a tuple of the new object or
            # current object and a boolean of if it was created
```

with this:

```
import pandas as pd
from myapp.models import glossary_entry

def pour_entire_entry_model():

    elements = glossary_entry.objects.all() 

    for element in elements:

        entry = acquired_terminology.objects.create()

        entry.Lemma = element.Lemma
        entry.Acronym = element.Acronym
        entry.Definizione = element.Definizione 

            # creates a tuple of the new object or
            # current object and a boolean of if it was created
```

Comment: I followed your steps because I had the same root problem and recreated your errors along the way up until the last step. When i run "python3 manage.py myscript" it just tells me "Unknown command: 'query_and_save_temperatures'". Any tips? Did your solutions still use the management/commands folder?

Comment: In django you should always run your app by running `python manage.py runserver`.  Still, it sounds like some path or directory name is mismatching. However, that is too little information to find out what is wrong. You'd better open a question providing all the context to reproduce the error.

Comment: Okay. Thank you by the way for updating your question and providing your solution. Helps a lot.